# required: double [] found: no arguments

Tags: java, arrays, list, average

Code:

```
 ArrayList <Integer> marks = new ArrayList();

 String output = "Class average:" + calculateAverage() + "\n" + "Maximum mark:" +  
 calculateMaximum() + "\n" +"Minimum mark:" + calculateMinimum() + "\n" + "Range of 
 marks:" + range;

 analyzeTextArea.setText(output);

 private double calculateAverage(double [] marks) {
 double sum = 0;
 for (int i=0; i< marks.length; i++) {
 sum += marks[i];
 }
 return sum / marks.length;
 }
```

Disregard the other things inside the string (minimum, maximum, and range) but for this line,

```
 String output = "Class average:" + calculateAverage() + "\n" + "Maximum mark:" +  
 calculateMaximum() + "\n" +"Minimum mark:" + calculateMinimum() + "\n" + "Range of 
 marks:" + range;
```

I get an error:

> required: double []
>   found: no arguments

Why do I get this error and what should I change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling the method calculateAverage this way: `calculateAverage()`, without any argument. But the method is declared this way:

```
private double calculateAverage(double [] marks)
```

It thus needs one argument of type `double[]`, but you don't pass anything.

Comment: It's an array called marks so I changed it to calculateAverage(marks) but I still get the same error.

Comment: No, now you should get the error `reauired double[]: found ArrayList`.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's true, so what's the problem now?

Comment: The problem is that an ArrayList<Integer> is not an array of doubles. If the train controller asks your ticket, you don't give him your shoes, do you? Same here: the method needs a double[], you must give it a double[]. You need to transform your List<Integer> into an array of doubles. Or you must change the method to take a List<Integer> as argument rather than a double[].

Comment: Still does not work, I tried both ways and I get the same errors.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem, instead of saying "doesn't work". We're not extra-lucid. We don't see your new code. We don't see the error message you get (and which contains meaningful information that you should read and understand)

Comment: I changed all the doubles in the method to int, like so: private int calculateAverage(int [] marks) {
    int sum = 0;  // sum of all the elements
    for (int i=0; i< marks.length; i++) {
    sum += marks[i];
    }
    return sum / marks.length;
    }

Comment: Let me repeat myself: an ArrayList<Integer> is not an array of ints. The method needs an int[], you must give it an int[]. You need to transform your List<Integer> into an array of ints. Or you must change the method to take a List<Integer> as argument rather than an int[].

Comment: "Or you must change the method to take a List<Integer> as argument rather than an int[]." I DID this.

Comment: No. The error message says: *required: int[] found: ArrayList*. So the method requires an int[]. You changed from double[] to int[]. Not from double[] to List<Integer>.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, so is this how it should look, private int calculateAverage(list <Integer> marks) ?

Comment: With an upper-case L. `List<Integer>`. Classes, by convention, always start with an upper-case in Java. And Java is case-sensitive. I think you should step back a little, and go back to the basics. Re-read your book. Learn what a class is. Learn where the javadoc is and how to use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11849/discussion-between-user1419306-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this:

```
String output = "Class average:" + calculateAverage() + ...
```

What's that meant to be calculating the average of? You've got to provide the method with some data to average. The same is going to be true of `calculateMaximum`, `calculateMinimum` etc. Without any context, those methods can't do anything.

Where are your actual marks stored? Presumably you have some sort of variable storing the marks - so pass that. For example:

```
String output = "Class average:" + calculateAverage(actualMarks) + ...
```

... except obviously with the real variable, or whatever you're using to store the marks.

Comment: It's an array called marks so I changed it like you said to calculateAverage(marks) but I still get the same error.

Comment: @user1419306: I suspect you didn't get the *same* error - just a similar one (given your discussion above). It's very important to *read error messages carefully*.

Answer (score 1):

private double calculateAverage(double [] marks) is the method declaration, so when its called it must have and argument of double array

eg:

calculateAverage(double_value_array);

Answer (score 0):

You can call it this way:

```
double d[] = {1, 2, 3};
double ret = calculateAverage(d);
System.out.println(ret);
```